# Merging RDD records to obtain a single Row with multiple conditional counters

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As a little bit of context, what I'm trying to achieve here is given multiple rows grouped by a certain set of keys, after that first reduce I would like to group them in a general row by, for example, date, with each of the grouped counters previously calculated. This may not seem clear by just reading it so here is an example output (quite simple, nothing complex) of what should happen.

```
(("Volvo", "T4", "2019-05-01"), 5)
(("Volvo", "T5", "2019-05-01"), 7)
(("Audi", "RS6", "2019-05-01"), 4)
```

And once merged those Row objects...

```
date         , volvo_counter     , audi_counter
"2019-05-01" , 12                , 4
```

I reckon this is quite a corner case and that there may be different approaches but I was wondering if there was any solution within the same RDD so there's no need for multiple RDDs divided by counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is a pivot. You talk about RDDs so I assume that your question is: "how to do a pivot with the RDD API?". As far as I know there is no built-in function in the RDD API that does it. You could do it yourself like this:

```scala
// let's create sample data
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (("Volvo", "T4", "2019-05-01"), 5),
  (("Volvo", "T5", "2019-05-01"), 7),
  (("Audi", "RS6", "2019-05-01"), 4)
))

// If the keys are not known in advance, we compute their distinct values
val values = rdd.map(_._1._1).distinct.collect.toSeq
// values: Seq[String] = WrappedArray(Volvo, Audi)

// Finally we make the pivot and use reduceByKey on the sequence
val res = rdd
    .map{ case ((make, model, date), counter) =>
        date -> values.map(v => if(make == v) counter else 0)
    }
    .reduceByKey((a, b) => a.indices.map(i => a(i) + b(i)))

// which gives you this
res.collect.head
// (String, Seq[Int]) = (2019-05-01,Vector(12, 4))
```

Note that you can write much simpler code with the SparkSQL API:

```scala
// let's first transform the previously created RDD to a dataframe:
val df = rdd.map{ case ((a, b, c), d) => (a, b, c, d) }
    .toDF("make", "model", "date", "counter")

// And then it's as simple as that:
df.groupBy("date")
  .pivot("make")
  .agg(sum("counter"))
  .show

+----------+----+-----+
|      date|Audi|Volvo|
+----------+----+-----+
|2019-05-01|   4|   12|
+----------+----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what happens when a case is 0? I'm seeing some 'null' values after pivoting and not so sure how to avoid them. Would be enough with an after mapping?

Comment: If for a given date you don't have any row about a given category, you will end up with a null value. If you'd rather have a `0`, you can use `.na.fill(0)`.

Comment: Such a fast response, thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Glad I could help, I was just looking for an answer myself when I saw your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to do with DataFrame:

```
   val data = Seq(
      Record(Key("Volvo", "2019-05-01"), 5),
      Record(Key("Volvo", "2019-05-01"), 7),
      Record(Key("Audi", "2019-05-01"), 4)
    )

    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

    val df = rdd.toDF()

    val modelsExpr = df
      .select("key.model").as("model")
      .distinct()
      .collect()
      .map(r => r.getAs[String]("model"))
      .map(m => sum(when($"key.model" === m, $"value").otherwise(0)).as(s"${m}_counter"))

    df
      .groupBy("key.date")
      .agg(modelsExpr.head, modelsExpr.tail: _*)
      .show(false)
```